# Homebrew Cryomancers?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew

So I was thinking of making a cryomancer for the next campaign I am in and as I was looking through all the spells I noticed that there weren't enough ice/water spells to create a fully focused cryomancer.

So if there are any homebrew cryomancers anyone knows about that are

- Balanced.
- Tested already.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your core issue is that there aren't enough ice- or water-themed spells. Currently, Wizards have access to the most number of ice spells, at least, and Druids have access to the most water spells. Given that cyromancer speaks to me of being more about ice than water, I'd say a Wizard is probably what you're looking for, rather than a "homebrew cyromancer" class (if that's what you meant).

That said, the core issue is still not resolved just by picking Wizard as your character's class. The issue here is that there aren't enough ice-themed spells. I think the easiest solution would be to...

#### Work with your DM to homebrew/reflavour some ice-themed spells to add to the Wizard spell list

The easiest thing to do would be to pick some existing spells from the Wizard spell list and reflavour them to deal cold damage (perhaps renaming them as well, but otherwise following the description of the spell being changed exactly). This would make any balance issues less likely to occur. Which spells to reflavour would be down to you and your DM, though, since they might not be too keen on a cold-damage fireball, etc.

Alternatively, come up with brand new spells with your DM. This is more work, since it's not just reflavouring an existing spell to do cold damage, and since anything you come up with should be OK'd with your DM, reviewing your brand new cold-damage spells would be more effort than simply white-listing a few existing spells to be reflavoured, but again, this is something to work with your DM about.

Comment: I feel kind of stupid for not thinking about that lol, thanks man that is probably my chance without making things complicated for the DM and the players

Comment: Wizard paths also don't focus on the spells themselves but give other abilities instead, as there are even few of each school at each level sometimes. Previous editions gave you additional spots to memorize spells of that school. In this one you get themed abilities instead.

Comment: What I am doing to play a Cryomancer is picking the Loremaster archetype from UA so I can just change any elemental spell into cold damage.

Comment: @Nathan I knew there was a UA somewhere that could do damage type change. The Lore Master is generally held to be pretty horrendously OP, though; it is not what anyone considers balanced.

Comment: @Carcer Yeah it seemed a little overpowered so I limited the damage type changes to Cold/Lightning/Fire/Poison and any save change has to be restricted to the physical/mental stat it already was so I can't make Fireball a CHA save for example but instead a STR save.